# как передать post-запрос из приложения на сервер

Tags: php, java, android, post

Дело в том, что мне надо передать post запрос php файлу. При передаче эти запросы присваиваются переменным ( $name=$_GET['name']; ). Как такое реализовать? Пробовал ч\з HttpClient, не получилось из-за того, что студия не видит этой библиотеки, пробовал ч\з HttpComponent, но выводил ошибки при присваивании URL переменной и при создании объекта HttpURLConnection. Подскажите каким ещё образом можно отправить эти данные или как можно перейти по ссылке подобного типа http://site.ru/file.php?name=qwerty при этом, что бы на экране ничего не происходило?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать это через либу OkHttp или даже через Retrofit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение вопроса. Во-первых, нужно использовать AsyncTask, для параллельных, фоновых действий, во-вторых вот код:

```
public String id = "";
public String name = "";
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Object... voids) {

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://site.ru/get.php/?id=" + id + "&name=" + name));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();

                System.out.println(out.toString());
            } else{
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал библиотеку Retrofit. 
Вот туториал на русском https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5HX_GoyaDs
На английском их гараздо больше, и они более расширенные.